# ReactJS showing list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I have an array of objects(a list of comments to some item), and I want to display it on the page. But not all of those comments! First 10 for example. And below that list i wanna render some kinda button. And if a user wants to see next 10 comments, he needs to click on that button.

Something like 'show more' in 'Youtube'.

I can render all those comments! But I don't need that. I need to display 10 comments ... each time the button is being clicked.

Can anyone help me please
Thanks

Comment: please show what you have tried so far, or post some code to show where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I presume (from the tag) that you get the comments from your flux store. Instead of getting all comments and then filtering in the component, you'd better get only 10 comments from the server, and build a new flux action like `LOAD_MORE_COMMENTS` that will be called when the user clicks on a button, that would make the ajax call to complete the dataset.

Comment: @Pandaiolo That's the best option. Let the server handle the number of comments passed to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's assume that you have 20 comments in an array

```
var comments = getComments() // returns list of 20 comments
```

Then you can use `slice` to get the first 10 comments, then map them to actual `HTML`

```
var commentsAsHTML = comments.slice(0, this.state.limitTo).map(comment => {
   return <li key={comment.id}>{comment.text}</li>
});
```

To add the "Load more" functionality, we will have `limitTo` state

```
limitTo = 10;
```

And with each "Load more" action, we will increment this limit by **10** for example.

```
onLoadMore () {
   this.setState({
      limitTo: this.state.limitTo + 10
   });
}
```

Comment: This implementation will be problematic if your app must scale to many (thousands) of comments - see my comment on the original question

Comment: @Pandaiolo You are right, I just implemented a solution for his CURRENT situation. Maybe he can't change the APIs.

Comment: `comments.slice(0, 10).map(...` should be `comments.slice(0, this.state.limitTo).map(...`

Comment: so now, instead of 'slicing' from '0 to '10', i'm gonna slice from '0' to 'this.state.limitTo' everytime a user clickes the button

Answer (score 1):

from the below code you can get the basic idea of how a `loadmore` component can be implemented from scratch,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Router extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5];
    this.state = {
      count: 5,
      defaultCount: 5,
    };
  }
  handleCount() {
    let count = this.state.defaultCount;
    count = count + this.state.count;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
  render() {
    const count = this.state.count;
    const showData = (item, index) => {
     return ((index < count) ? <li>{item}</li> : '');
    };
 return (
   <div>
     {this.data.map(showData)}
     <a href="#" onClick={this.handleCount.bind(this)}>Load</a>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

**what I have done here:**

> i) take an array with 15 elements;
>
> ii) initialize the state with `count` and `defaultcount`
>
> iii) then i have map the `data` array to show the item on `showData` function
>
> iV) on the `return` of `showData` function i have checed if the `index of array element` is less than the `count` variable.
>
> v) and each time you click on `loadmore` button it will call the `handleCount` function and increate the `count` value by `defaultCount`.
>
> vi) after the `count` variable updated than more 5 array element will be shown on this example

that's it, i hope you get the basic idea of `lodemore`